# Where should code to build view models go?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

When building a view model in asp.net's MVC3, where should the code go to instantiate the objects of that view model?  I am doing it mostly in the controller right now, aside from the code to query the database. Here is an example in code:

View Model:

```
public class WorkListVM
{
    //list for employees
    [Display(Name = "Select A Employee")]
    [Required]
    public int? EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public GenericSelectList EmployeeList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Code:

```
        //build view model
        var vm = new WorkListVM();

        //build employee list
        vm.EmployeeList = new GenericSelectList(0,"-- Select Employee --");
        var employees = new List<Employee>();
        using (var gr = new GenericRepo<Employee>())
        {
            employees = gr.Get().ToList();
        }
        foreach(var employee in employees)
        {
            var gl = new GenericListItem();
            gl.Id = employee.EmployeeId;
            gl.DisplayFields = employee.FirstName + " " + employee.LastName;
            vm.EmployeeList.Values.Add(gl);
        }
```

Generic Select List is a simple class to hold the data that goes in the helper `@html.dropdownfor`'s `SelectList`. I build these selectlist's, and also build similar data configurations for view models inside of the controller code. The controller hosting this code has a total of 109 lines of code, so it is not huge or out of control. However, I am always striving to reduce redundancy and sometimes the code in `//build employee list` ends up being copy pasted (ugh, i hate copy paste) into other controllers.

Is there a better place to have this code? Should I maybe be using the factory pattern to build the data for these selectlists / other view data objects?

**EDIT**

Thanks for all your help. Here is what I ended up doing. I ended up making a method inside the generic select list class very similar to the .ToSelectList(...) suggested by Richard and Jesse:

```
    public class GenericSelectList
{
    public List<GenericListItem> Values { get; set; }
    public int StartValue { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public GenericSelectList(int StartValue = 0, string Message = "select")
    {
        Values = new List<GenericListItem>();
        this.StartValue = StartValue;
        this.Message = Message;
    }

    public void BuildValues<T>(List<T> items, Func<T, int> value, Func<T, string> text) where T : class
    {
        this.Values = items.Select(f => new GenericListItem()
        {
            Id = value(f),
            DisplayFields = text(f)
        }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you return your viewmodel to a view, then the code goes in the controller.

Comment: @白ジェームス - Yes, at the end of this actionresult method is `return View(vm);`. The view is strong typed `@model WorkListVM`. Some of this code is used multiple times (in different controllers). Wouldn't it make sense to have a factory that wraps the creation of these viewmodel objects in order to reduce redundancy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the business logic that goes into creating a view model is quite complex I generally extract it into a helper method that I can test independently of the controller.

However, that aside, your creation of the view model is perfectly fine within the controller as it is. As has already been noted, how your generating the select list could be made much simpler (not to mention reusable).

Here is a ToSelectList extension of IEnumerable along with an example of usage:

```
public static List<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T>( this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Func<T, string> value, Func<T, string> text, string defaultOption)
{
    var items = enumerable.Select(f => new SelectListItem()
                                          {
                                              Text = text(f) ,
                                              Value = value(f)
                                          }).ToList();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(defaultOption))
    {
                    items.Insert(0, new SelectListItem()
                        {
                            Text = defaultOption,
                            Value = string.Empty
                        });
    }

    return items;
}
```

Within your view model you could add a property like so:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Employees { get; set; }
```

Within your controller (i'm assuming that your repo is returning IEnumberable):

```
var employees = new IEnumerable<Employee>();
using (var gr = new GenericRepo<Employee>())
{
    employees = gr.Get();
}

vm.Employees = employees.ToSelectList(x=>x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName, x=>x.Id, "-- Select Employee --")
```

And then to setup your drop down list in the view it would look something like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmployeeId, Model.employees)
```

Comment: +1 - Great minds think alike ;) And you saved me a translation!

Comment: Very well written extension, thank you for the input on this subject :)

Comment: @Jesse - Your idea for an extension was good, but I decided to make it a method inside of the class I use for select lists which worked out great! See my edit for the implementation. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to avoid redundant code, you should extract the common parts into helper methods. In the most simple form, you can use static methods for this.

Building view models in the controller is generally the right approach, except if there are special reasons against it.

You can structure your code any way you want. Use standard techniques to cope with complexity such as helper methods and (sparingly) abstractions. No need to go complex when simple is enough.

Answer (score 2):

1 - You could add an extension method to `IEnumerable<Employee>` or `IQueryable<Employee>` that returns your `GenericSelectList`. Advantages - you can re-use against any collection of employee, i.e. a filtered list, and quite nice calling syntax; you can customise how the select list is formed on a case by case basis. Disadvantages - you'll have to write one of these methods for each type.

2 - You could change that extension method to work with a generic, that works against `IEnumerable<T>` and produces a `GenericSetList` based on `Expression` inputs. Advantages - Your method is now truly generic, i.e. write once and re-use. You could do this in such a way that it combines with 1 so that your 1-per-class function uses the generic to save duplication. Disadvantages - assumes comfort in using expressions and the like.

3 - You could have factory methods that return ViewModels.

These things can also work in combination as well, and should help remove copy/paste code and promote re-use and testability.

Edit - here is one way that no. 2 could be implemented (in VB but translation to C# is trivial). I would then add over-loads for the useful permutations of inputs.

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports System.Linq.Expressions

Module IQueryableExtensions

    <Extension()>
    Public Function ToSelectList(Of T)(source As IEnumerable(Of T), nameExpression As Expression(Of Func(Of T, String)), valueExpression As Expression(Of Func(Of T, String)), selectedExpression As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean)), additionalItems As IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)) As IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)
        Return additionalItems.Union(
            source.Select(Function(x) New SelectListItem With {
                              .Text = nameExpression.Compile.Invoke(x),
                              .Value = valueExpression.Compile.Invoke(x),
                              .Selected = selectedExpression.Compile.Invoke(x)
                          }
                      )
                  )
    End Function

End Module
```

Sample usage:

```
    Dim People As New List(Of Person) From {New Person With {.Name = "Richard", .ID = 1}}

    Dim sl = People.ToSelectList(Function(p) p.Name,
                                 Function(p) p.ID,
                                 Function(p) p.ID = 1,
                                 {New SelectListItem With {.Value = 0,
                                                           .Text = "Please Select A Person"}})
```

Comment: I could do #2, in that I would add a generic response for select list generation. However, it would require reflection. Would it be unwise to use reflection in the repository?

Comment: Are you saying reflection because you want to include the class name? There are other ways round that, give me a sec and I'll post a sample.

Comment: @TravisJ - there you go - a possible implementation with no reflection.

Comment: Thank you for the very verbose example :) However, the reflection I was talking about would be to retain the generic aspect of the repository in that no fields would need to be explicitly defined. Thus, reflection would determine all the fields of the object to be returned and then return them as a selectlistitem. In your example, would this method then be an extension to be used in the controller (leaving the repository untouched)? Sorry, my vb is a little weak.

Comment: @TravisJ - these are extension methods, they sit in a Module in VB or in a static class in C#, which I would normally put into an "Extensions" namespace and name {typeName}Extensions - so this would be IEnumerableExtensions because it extends IEnumerable. I would probably combine 2 and 3, and so a Factory method would be using the  generic extension as part of building a ViewModel. It is something that would process the output from your Repository.Get() method, so it would normally be called from the same thing that calls the repository, not inside the repository itself. Want it in C# as well?

Comment: @TravisJ, while i was typing away I didn't see the edit Richard had made. I had added a similar example but in C#

Comment: @Jesse - Thanks, I saw your example and appreciated it as well. (at)RichardW - http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/ actually has a pretty nice tool for conversion so the vb was not much of an issue.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the right way, but I use it and it helps me keep control of everything.

a controller in my eyes does things like update sessions, cookies and then returns a view. I never use it for sorting any data or creating objects to send to the view.

(i might cheat if its a one off one liner :p)

all that sort of stuff I add to a helper class. Every time i feel a copy and paste come on I create a new method in my helper and call that instead.

plus, you get a nice sense of well being when 3 days later you need to use the method and its all there waiting.

Martyn

Comment: So perhaps I should just make a generic helper method using reflection to manage creating these select lists...